# Django: How can I annotate on the Sum of values in a ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: django

I have two models, `Item` and `Vote`:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name=CharField(max_length=75)

class Vote(models.Model):
    item = ForeignKey(Item)
    value = IntegerField()
```

I want to provide a queryset with a list of items in order of the sum of the value of the votes. I'm trying:

```
items = Item.objects.annotate(Sum('votes__value')).order_by('votes__value')
```

but in the situation where I have two votes - one `value = 0` and one `value = 1` - I'm getting a queryset of two `Item` instances, for which `item1 == item2`!

How do I properly construct this queryset? Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier seeing what's in items, but as a first remark, shouldn't it be Item.objects.annotate(Sum('votes__value')).order_by('votes__value__sum').

Comment: @JulienGrégoire items is only one item, with a name, and two votes. One vote has value=1 and one has value=0. The fact that there is only one item instance in the database but my call returns two is what astounds me!

Trying your solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
items = Item.objects.values('item').annotate(votes_value=Sum('votes')).order_by('votes')
```

or

```
items = Item.objects.values('item').annotate(votes_value=Sum('votes'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Item.objects.annotate(votes_total=Sum('votes__value')).order_by('votes_total')
```